# random elements from a list DURING the addition

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, random

There are 20 names in my code.
my function has 2 options to add elements to a list I've:

**1.**

Inserting all the 20 names to the list:

```
public void addNames() {
    list.add("name1");
    list.add("name2");
    ...
    list.add("name20");
}
```

**2.**

Adding only 5 random names(from the 20 names) to the list. For doing it, I thought about 2 ways. What's the best way to random 5 names from the 20? maybe you have a better way.

**A.**

Using a random set of indices (each value will be between 0 to 19 because there are 20 names) and before the 'add' I'll check if adding them or not by some counter:

```
public void addNames() {
    // adding 5 random indices between 0 to 19 to the set
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Random r = new Random();
    Set<Integer> indices = new HashSet<>(numRandomNames); //==5
    for (int i = 0; i < numRandomNames; ++i) {
        int index = r.nextInt(numNames - 0); //==19
        indices.add(index);
    }

    int counter = 0;
    if (indices.contains(counter)) {
        list.add("name1");
    }
    counter++;
    if (indices.contains(counter)) {
        list.add("name2");
    }
    counter++;
    if (indices.contains(counter)) {
        list.add("name3");
    }
    ...
}
```

**B.**

RandomList that extends List and overrides the 'add' function to do the same as '**A.**' does BUT the override 'add' will decide whether adding the value inside the function so my function will look the same as **1.** with the **override** 'add' function

**Do you think about a better solution? if not, then which one is better? (A or B?).** I just saw that people recommends not to extend the java collection but I think it's the best solution from these 2 solutions.

**NOTE**

**====**

my code can have 10000 names or more even so I don't want to add all the 10,000 names to this\other list and then random 5 of them to other list. I prefer to do it DURING the addition in order to avoid many places of the list while I don't really need them.

**EDIT**

an answer to ProgrammerTrond:

I'm not sure I'll do it but what I asked me to show is my suggestion of 2.B:

```
public class RandomList<Integer> implements List<Integer> {
    private int addCallsCounter;
    private Set<Integer> setIndices = null;

    public RandomList(final int numElements, final int maxVal, final int minVal) {
        addCallsCounter = 0;
        setIndices =  new HashSet<Integer>(numElements);
        Random r = new Random();
        while (setIndices.size() < numElements) {
            int index = r.nextInt(maxVal - minVal + 1) + minVal;
            if (setIndices.contains(index) == false) {
                setIndices.add(index);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer object) {
        if (setIndices.contains(addCallsCounter++)) {
            this.add(object);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and from my code I'll do so:

```
RandomList randList = new RandomList(5);
randList.add("name1");
randList.add("name2");
randList.add("name3");
...
randList.add("name19");
randList.add("name20");
```

but my problem is that I need to implement MANY abstract methods of List pfff. RandomList cann't be abstract too because then it won't be able to be instantiated.

Comment: where are your 10000 names stored?

Comment: it's not really 10,000 but it can be 20-100.
They are not stored, it's hardcoded as I showed.

Comment: are they stored in list?

Comment: no. they are not stored at all because I don't think it's my best way to store all of them in some list if I want to use only 5 random of them for the rest of my code

Comment: if you are not storing it anywhere then how you will refer to the Strings.

Comment: just hard coded such as "name1", "name2" and etc.. (I didn't store the names in any collection)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127948/discussion-between-android-jack-and-erez-shmiel).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
List<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> five_names = new ArrsyList<>();
List<String> allnames = new ArrayList<>();
```

store  five random values

```
for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++){

  int index_no = getrandomNumber();
  index.add(index_no);
  five_names.add(allnames.get(index_no));
}
```

getRandomNumber method:

```
public int getRandomNumber(){

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int x = rnd.nextInt(20);

    if(index.contains(x)){
       return getRandomNumber();
    }else{
       return x
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this? You don't need the random index list in your list implementation. Didn't you just want a method that would add to a list 5 random names drawn from a set of available names?

```
import java.util.*;
public class ListAdding {

    private static List<String> allNames = Arrays.asList("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Temp().test();
    }

    void test() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Bernie");
        addFiveRandom(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + list.get(i));
        }
        // Example: 0: Bernie
        // 1: name2
        // 2: name3
        // 3: name6
        // and so on  
    }

    void addFiveRandom(List<String> toBeAddedTo) {
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
        while (indices.size() < 5) {
            int newIndex = new Random().nextInt(5);
            if (!indices.contains(newIndex))
                indices.add(newIndex);
        }
        for (Integer index : indices) {
            toBeAddedTo.add(allNames.get(index));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this solution but I thought it's better to avoid using a new list with ALL the elements because I want to use only 5 of them for the rest of the code. The solution I thought about is using only 1 list and decides by itself if adding the value in a realtime.

Comment: Storing all the available names can be done outside the "add5Random" method if it's performance you're worried about. I also wanted to note that when you just use "nextInt(numNames - 0)" five times, some of those may be duplicate and then you'll get fewer than 5 random names. Will you consider showing us your code when it's done?